# Simple Proxy Can't Get JSON response

Tags: php, javascript, json, proxy, cross-domain

I am trying to connect to a site via a php proxy (this one: https://raw.github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/master/ba-simple-proxy.php), and this is the JavaScript function that does something with the response:

Edit: The code now looks like this. Still no cigar.

```
function exista(word) {

    alert(word);
    var proxy = 'ba-simple-proxy.php?url=';
    var uri = "http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/ff175/json/roen/" + word;
    uri = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    alert(proxy + uri);
    var cuvantulexista = 1;
    jQuery.ajax({
        "async": false,
        "url": proxy + uri,
        "dataType": 'json',
        "method": "GET",
        "success": function (data) {
            alert("HERE!");
            if (data.Error || data.Response)
                cuvantulexista = 0;
        }
    });
    return cuvantulexista;
}
```

The php file is situated in the same folder as the js file that contains the above function and in the public folder which contains the html file.

The problem is I don't get any response whatsoever and I can't really tell why.

I also included the php in the html like so:

```
<?php
    include("js/ba-simple-proxy.php");
?>
```

I am sorry for my extreme noobiness but it's my first time working with php and cross domain communication. Thank you. :)

Edit: The page is not hosted on a domain if that helps.

Edit2: So, I opened Google Chrome without --disable-web-security and I get this error again:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/bogdan/Scrabble-Online/public/ba-simple-proxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.wordreference.com%2F0.8%2Fff175%2Fjson%2Froen%2FRHE. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Yet, if I start it on localhost it doesn't show the message. It just doesn't connect. I am severely confused now.

Comment: And, yes, I need the response to be synchronous. :)

Comment: You might have a PHP error somewhere, try to turn on full error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`. Also check the JavaScript console - is there any error message?

Comment: Have you tried dataType:'jsonp'?  I recently worked on a proxy project  where I wrote a proxy server in C# and a web interface with the usual HTML/CSS/JS (jQuery).  I found a TON of problems and quirks with cross domain requests.  If I recall correctly, I think synchronous cross domain requests could not be done.

Comment: There are no error messages in the console. And I wanted to use a proxy so that I could get a synchronous response which JSONP is unable to give.

Comment: @Casteurr okay I misunderstood your problem, my apologies.

Comment: you need to encodeURIComponent() part of the url.

Comment: Done that. Still not getting connected. I changed the console.log(data) with an alert("HERE!"), but it never fires.

Comment: Ugh, getting a synchronous response using cross domain shouldn't be such a pain.

Comment: have you checked your browsers network pane to see if it's throwing a 500 or 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

To make a cross side request your target page needs to allow you to access:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

You can add this at the top of your proxy script. Better replace `*` with your domain.

However `file://` URLs can't be authorized. So you need to have a real domain.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744697/956397

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, like I said above if I start the page on localhost, using SimpleHTTPServer the error doesn't show up anymore. It just doesn't connect to the wordreference api using the proxy.